# LayerSlider. Where do I edit the slider thumbnail size

Tags: tags, slider, thumbnails, layer

I've been looking for hours: myself and by looking if others had the same problem. I cannot find where I can change the dimensions of the slider thumbnails.. Unfortunately for me I changed them myself a couple of days ago but cannot recall where it was.

Firebug comes with the 'element.style' which doesn't help..

Anyone..?

Comment: Inspect the thumbnail element, and see what class is in use, then you can write the same class name and have your height and width params set.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following parameters when initializing the slider:

```
$('#slider').layerSlider({
    tnWidth: 120,
    tnHeight: 72
});
```

source: http://www.docs.purethemes.net/sukces/layerslider/documentation/documentation.html